# node.js deleting mysql rows where id = socket.room

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-delete

I am  trying to add a command to my chatroom so admins can type /trunecate and clear all of the messages in just that room

my database that stores all of the messages stores the room that they belong to as socket.room-Chat so if you were in the general room it would be General-Chat

i have tried the following to get it to work but it still fails

`dbconnect.query('DELETE FROM messages WHERE room= ' + socket.room  , function(err, result) {if (err) {throw err;}`

`dbconnect.query('DELETE FROM messages WHERE room= ' + socket.room + '-Chat' , function(err, result) {if (err) {throw err;}`

but i keep getting this error in my console

`Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'General' in 'where clause'`

[here](http://chat.billischill.ga:8080) is the site you can use the /trunecate command but it will crash the server :( with that error

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes? room= \"' + socket.room + '\"

Comment: The query you need is ...where room = "General-Chat". What I said is that you should make sure the query has the quotes around General-Chat (")

Comment: That Worked perfectly thank you sorry